# It kept doubling

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Are to following sentences correct?

1. The company experienced a sharp rise by 11% in the very next year. And **the percentage doubled** in 1990 and 2015.
2. The population kept **doubling** each year.

Have I used 'doubled' correctly in the sentences?

Does it mean that if the original figure was 100, now it's 200 and next it'll be 400? Or does it go like 100, 200, 300 and so on?

Comment: This is a very confusing question. You ask if the sentences are correct AND you ask what they mean. Also you have asked about two different calculations.  In the first case, it doesn't even make sense. Double 11% is not any of those numbers. Really this is a question about mathematics, not English. However can you please explain what you actually want the sentences to *mean*. Also please choose one of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting off from

> The company experienced a sharp rise by 11% in the very next year. And the percentage doubled in 1990 and 2015.

let's say that you are referring to the company's annual profit in 1988 and that the value of such profit was 100,000 USD. From your sentence I would understand that the company's profit went up by 11% in 1989 to 111,000 USD. Then it went up another 22% in 1990 to 135,420 USD. Now, I am not sure what happens between 1991 and 2014, but I understand that it experienced another 22% increase in 2015 based on the profit of the previous year.

Maybe you meant

> The company experienced a sharp rise by 11% in the very next year. And the percentage doubled *between* 1990 and 2015.

This however is ambiguous. It can mean that the increase was twofold on a yearly basis between 1990 and 2015 or that it slowly grew to reach a 22% increase by 2015.

About

> The population kept doubling each year.

This simply means that each following year the population is twice of what is was the previous one, so if it was 1,000 in 1990, it would be 2,000 in 1991, 4,000 in 1992, 8,000 in 1993, etc.